# How to enable Server Side search with jQuery dataTables?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using `Datatables` with server side processing to display data. I have around 10000 rows of data which I would like to limit to make it more readable.

I would like to display only 50 rows of data in the datatable.

```
$('#dataTable3').dataTable({ 
        "sAjaxSource": "user_data.php",
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bPaginate":true,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,       
        "aoColumns": [      
        { mData: 'sno' } ,
        { mData: 'dob' } ,
        { mData: 'fullname' },
        { mData: 'email'}]      
    });
```

The server side PHP script limits the number of rows to 50 as shown :

```
SELECT * FROM users order by id desc limit 50
```

Now, the issue is if I want to search for a particular user, it is searching from the 50 rows of the Datatable. I would like to search on the server side as well. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: set serverSide:true.  In doing so, all control is turned over to the server.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide

Comment: and https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Have you tried anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules you have to consider when you are using server-side processing with **DataTables**.
On every `load` datatables executes, it sends some parameters to your server and it expects some others back to identify the **data**, **quantity** and **filters** to apply.

You need to read those on the request sent by `datatables` and apply them on you filters and data fetching on you database.

You can check how datatables sends the request in [this](https://coderexample.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/datatable_param.png) image.

As mentioned by @Bindrid, you can check the detailed definition of those parameters [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).
There is a good tutorial [here](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/) and [here](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html) that you can check how to do that using PHP.
And, of course, there is also the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) on the `datatables` documentation.